# How to email a list of user a custom message from excel file using Nodemailer SMTP

Tags: node.js, email, templates, automation, nodemailer

I have a excel file which looks like this:

```
name,email,message
John Smith, johnsmith@domain.com, b183fg
John Doe, johndoe@domain.com, wqeqdc
```

I need to send an email to the list of user in the excel file with an email template that look like this:

```
Hi {name},

{message}

Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create async or sync function based on your requirement, how you want to handle the response. Here is generic function that you can use to create the connection and send a mail with required parameters.

index.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
// create the configuration
const mailConfig = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",  
    secure: true,
    secureConnection: false, // TLS requires secureConnection to be false
    tls: {
        ciphers:'SSLv3'
    },
    requireTLS:true,
    port: 465,
    debug: true,
    auth: { 
        user: emailUser, 
        pass: process.env.ADMIN_PASSWORD
    } 
}); 
//export the function to send the mail
exports.sendMail= async (myParam ) => {
const emailUser = process.env.ADMIN_EMAIL;


// TODO implement
let mailDetails = { 
    from: emailUser, 
    to: myParam.to, 
    cc: myParam.cc, 
    subject: myParam.subject,
    html: myParam.message,
};
const data = await mailConfig.sendMail(mailDetails);

return data;
};
```

You can simply import and use this function, you can also change the its behavior like aysnc or synch.